Getting rid of pride according to chassidic masters
BH
Hi, in the book The Great Magid pg 88 [1] it says: The succession to the seat of the Baal Shem Tov posed a problem. The master had not designated a successor in his will.
Each of the disciples had his own spheres in which he excelled,
but the situation called for someone with over-all qualifications.
A Chassidic tradition has it that eight months before his passing,
on Hoshana Rabhah 5520, Rabbi Israel foretold a group of his
disciples that he would not survive that year and consequently
they should seek a new master for themselves. That particular
group, still young apprentices, suggested the name of a certain
saint and the Baal Shem Tov advised them: "Go to him and
test him. Ask him to show you the way to rid yourselves of
pride.[2] If he will suggest to you a way to do so, know that he is
not the right man; but if he will exclaim "may G-d help” then
attach yourselves to him ..[3]
Do the continuation of the of Chabad Rebbes teach this lesson also that the only way to get rid of pride is to keep praying to Hashem or was there a new inovation some how that was created after made to completly get rid of it as you always hear about consepts like getting rid of all the chometz which stands for the yeshus and getting rid of all the yeshus ect.
Souces
[1] https://hebrewbooks.org/15757 Pg 88
[2] [Part of the comentary from the book] Based on numerous dicta in Talmud, Midrashim and Zohar,
Chassidism teaches that pride, self-enhancement, is tantamount to extreme impurity and is the root of misguided passions and evil; see
Kether Shem Tov , sect. 376 (and my notes ad loc)  Sefer Baal Shem
Tov , vol. II, p.101ff. Thus pride above all is the sin man must guard himself against, up to his very last moment. The Baal Shem Tov is said to have prayed on his death-bed, in the very last moments of his life: "Do not bring me into the path of pride” ( Psalms XXXVI: 12); see Sefer Baal Shem Tov, vol. II, p. 106 note 13, and p.246f.
[3] [continuation from the comments]  Sefer Baal Shem Tov , vol. II, p. 106 note 13.

I don't think that anyone holds that getting rid of Pride, or any bad Midah, can be done by praying. That would go against all mussar sources and more. That's why stories are stories and sometimes need much skepticism.

Hi this question says it was closed because it’s not clear. Can who ever closed this question please explain what was not clear about it that it explicitly needed to be closed?
